# handshake_failure from cloudflare ssl

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I'm using FastSpring payment, the problem is when I'm making payment in FastSpring and returning to my website, it's giving me Http notification issue:

```
    -- Error --
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

-- Request --
POST https://domain.com/fastspring/activate`
```

So the http notification can't be made successfully

I'm using Cloduflare SSL + Nginx

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess because your question lacks the necessary details for a more detailed analysis:

This might be caused by the Java application not supporting [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). SNI is only supported in JDK 1.7+. And at least Cloudflare Free SSL works only if the client supports SNI.

Comment: Additionally the supported protocols and ciphers are mostly known to be broken in Java.